# Select consecutive elements that satisfy a certain condition as separate arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an array of values, I want to select multiple sequences of consecutive elements that satisfy a condition. The result should be one array for each sequence of elements.

For example I have an array containing both negative and positive numbers. I need to select sequences of negative numbers, with each sequence in a separate array.
Here is an example :

```
import numpy as np

# Example data
values = np.array([1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3, 4, 5, 6, -7, -8, 10])

mask = values < 0
```

Here is how the output should look like :

```
Array 1:

[-1 -2 -3]

Array 2:

[-7 -8]
```

I tried to do it using `numpy.split`, but it became more like spaghetti code. I was wondering is there a Pythonic way to do this task?

Comment: when you say "*in consecutive order*" does this mean that the negative values should decrement by 1? What should be the output for `values = np.array([1, 2, 3, -1, -5, -3, 4, 5, 6, -7, -8, 10])`

Comment: I meant consecutive order based on their index. So the answer for this example will be `[-1, -5, -3], [-7, -8]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

##### clustering groups of negative numbers

If you only want to group the chunks of negative values, irrespective of their relative values, then simply compute a second mask to identify the starts of each negative chunk:

```
mask = values < 0
mask2 = np.r_[True, np.diff(mask)]
out = np.array_split(values[mask], np.nonzero(mask2[mask])[0][1:])
```

Output: `[array([-1, -7, -3]), array([-7, -8])]`

##### clustering groups of negative numbers if they are successive in value

If you want to cluster the negative values that also a successively decreasing (e.g. `-1, -2, -3, -5, -6` would form 2 clusters: `-1, -2, -3` and `-5, -6`. Then I would use [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas):

- convert to `Series`
- identify the negative values
- create a grouper for consecutive negative values (`(~mask).cumsum()`)
- add the index (or a range) to group the successive
- `groupby`

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(values)

# mask to keep negative values
mask = s<0
# group consecutive negatives
group1 = (~mask).cumsum()
# group successive decrementing values
s2 = s+s.index
group2 = s2.ne(s2.shift()).cumsum()

out = [g.to_numpy() for k, g in s[mask].groupby([group1, group2])]
```

Output: `[array([-1, -2, -3]), array([-7, -8]), array([-7])]`

Intermediates:

```
     s   mask  s2  group1  group2
0    1  False   1       1       1
1    2  False   3       2       2
2    3  False   5       3       3
3   -1   True   2       3       4 # out 1
4   -2   True   2       3       4 #
5   -3   True   2       3       4 #
6    4  False  10       4       5
7    5  False  12       5       6
8    6  False  14       6       7
9   -7   True   2       6       8  # out 2 
10  -8   True   2       6       8  #
11  -7   True   4       6       9    # out 3
12  10  False  22       7      10
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to get the result you want:

```
import itertools

out = [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(values, key=lambda v: v < 0) if k]
```

Output:

```
[[-1, -2, -3], [-7, -8]]
```

Comment: No need to filter after the list comprehension, do it within it: `[list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(values, key=lambda v: v < 0) if k]` ;)

Comment: @mozway thanks - not sure what happened to the brain there. I've edited the answer

Answer (score -2):

Here's an easy-to-understand solution using only pure Python:

```
# Example data
my_list = [1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3, 4, 5, 6, -7, -8, 10]
my_condition = lambda x: x < 0

# Get list of True, False values for whether elements satisfy the condition
mask = [my_condition(x) for x in my_list]
# Get list of indices in the list where the condition goes from being True to False
breakpoints = [i for i in range(1, len(mask)) if mask[i] != mask[i-1]]
# Get the sublists satisfying the condition
sublists = [my_list[a:b] 
            for a, b in zip([0, *breakpoints[:-1]], breakpoints)
            if all(my_condition(x) for x in my_list[a:b])]

print(sublists)
```

Output:

```
[[-1, -2, -3], [-7, -8]]
```